# Ctrl-C does not work in tmux window

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, tmux

I have a Mini2440 ARM Board, and I have put a base Debian 6.0 system on it using `multistrap`.

I have used `tmux` to run several processes in defferent windows from `/etc/rc.local`. I connect to the board using its serial port and an inittab entry to run `getty` on that port. I use `picocom` as serial communicator.

when root logs in, `~/.bashrc` attaches him to the already running tmux server, and processes can be easily monitored. the actual command is `exec tmux attach-session -t "main"`. tmux runs with default config.

everything works, except one of the processes (a shell script around `pppd`) does not receive Ctrl-C from terminal, while other processes do. also Ctrl-\ works. also `kill -INT <pppd_pid>` works, but `kill -INT <shellscript_pid>` does not.

I really need Ctrl-C to work. What is wrong with this setup?